# Sort query by field related to another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a table in my SQL Server database called `dayorder`, with the fields:

```
dayorder_cod (autoinc id),
dayorder_number (order number),
dayorder_sequence (order sequence)
dayorder_parent (parent order, can be null).
```

So I can have, for example, orders 100, 200, 998 and 999, with 100 being the parent of 998 and 999.

I want to sort the result as follows: 100, 998, 999, 200, i.e., the children of an order come just below it´s parent.

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No join needed:

if `dayorder_parent` references `dayorder_number`, then:

```
select d.*
from dayorder d
order by 
  isnull(d.dayorder_parent,d.dayorder_number)
  , d.dayorder_number
```

if `dayorder_parent` references `dayorder_cod`, then:

```
select d.*
from dayorder d
order by 
  isnull(d.dayorder_parent,d.dayorder_cod)
  , d.dayorder_cod
```

if `dayorder_sequence` is important to the order

```
select d.*
from dayorder d
order by 
  isnull(d.dayorder_parent,d.dayorder_cod)
  , d.dayorder_sequence
```

How it works: the query results are ordered by the `dayorder_parent`, but the initial row for each order will have a value of `NULL` for `dayorder_parent`.

Using `isnull(d.dayorder_parent,d.dayorder_number)` we can say that when an order doesn't have a parent, use its `dayorder_number` instead. Children of 100 get grouped with 100, and each group is further ordered by their individual `dayorder_number`.

note: you can use `coalesce()` instead of `isnull()` to get the same results. I tend to use `coalesce()` only when I need to get the first non-null value from a set of 3 or more values, as `isnull()` only supports two parameters.

- [`isnull()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
- [`coalesce()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: That's it! Can you please explain me how this works?

Comment: Added an explanation, does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM dayorder AS t1
LEFT JOIN dayorder AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.cod
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.parent, t1.cod), t1.cod
```

**Edit:**

In case `sequence` field determines order in your table, then you can use:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM dayorder AS t1
LEFT JOIN dayorder AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.cod
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.sequence, t1.sequence), t1.sequence
```

Comment: @aseolin In what way? Simply replace `cod` field by the field that determines order in your table.